# ¿Por qué el resultado no da lo que se espera?

Tags: python-3.x

Para obtener ciertas estadísticas de un recorrido, se pide realizar un programa que dada una distancia, entregue la velocidad en kilómetros por hora y en metros por segundo. Para esto, existen dos variables tiempo y distancia que vienen en segundos y kilómetros respectivamente. Tu programa debe guardar en la variable resultado un string, por ejemplo, para el siguiente caso:

tiempo = 1

distancia = 0.01

La variable resultado debería tener lo siguiente:

"La velocidad es 36.0 km/h o 10.0 m/s"

Y este es mi código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
def velocidad(distancia, tiempo):

  resultado = ""

  velocidad = distancia / tiempo

  a = round((float(velocidad) * 3600),6)

  b = round((float(velocidad) * 1000),6)

  resultado = str(a) +" " "km/h" " " "o" " " + str(b) +" " "m/s"
  print("La velocidad es", str(resultado))

  return resultado

#Con distancia en km y tiempo en segundos

distancia = 0.01

tiempo = 1

velocidad (distancia, tiempo)
```

Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Hola Maria podrias declarar velocidad=distancia / tiempo, despues de la variable resultado ?

Comment: Puedes agregar el código como texto no como imagen.

Comment: Puedo declarar velocidad=distancia/tiempo debajo de la variable resultado, y si me da, pero el programa que me califica sigue saliendo como error. 
Ya copie el código como texto.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: **El que falla es el programa que califica.** Te muestra como datos correctos los que inmediatamente después va a llamar incorrectos. La imagen del error revela que la "chambonada" está en otro sitio.

Comment: @quevedo muchas gracias! Como apenas estoy aprendiendo, es difícil saber si el código se encuentra correcto completamente

Comment: ~_ - : para eso estamos.

Comment: Aparentemente el programa corrector espera que la función retorne lo mismo que tú has impreso. Pero no lo hace, pues imprimes "La velocidad es xxxxxx" pero retornas solo "xxxxxxx"

Answer (score 1):

les dejo una solución que también paso las pruebas. Es similar a la de arriba, tiene algunas cositas distintas. Espero que sirva el aporte.

```py
def velocidad(distancia, tiempo):
    
    dist_km = distancia
    dist_m =  distancia * 1000
    time_s = tiempo
    time_h = tiempo / 3600

    vel_kmh = dist_km / time_h
    vel_ms = dist_m / time_s

    resultado = f"La velocidad es " + str(vel_kmh) + " km/h o " + str(vel_ms) + " m/s"
    return resultado
```

Answer (score -4):

El que falla es el programa que califica?

Aca esta la solucion 100%:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Omite el uso de groserías hacia cualquier persona por favor, en caso contrario es seguro puedan levantarte un reporte

Comment: Por favor, lee el [código de conducta](/conduct). En lugar de decir groserías a un usuario que ni siquiera las va a leer (porque las menciones en respuestas no se notifican), era más sencillo decir _el programa espera que retornes dentro del resultado la cadena "La velocidad es "_.

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).